# Sortable Data and Update Datebase Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to get this sortable code to work, and I have gotten it to work on `<li>`s like in the UI examples, but now I am using `<div>`s which doesn't really make a difference, but I think it complicates things a little.

So here is my sortable code with some sort of update ajax attached:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".heriyah" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".heriyah",
        handle: ".handle",
        cancel: ".add",
        update : function () {
        var order = $('.heriyah').sortable('serialize');
        $("#sortable").load("sortable.php?"+order);
        },
        receive: function(event, ui){
           alert('RECEIVE: ' + $(ui.sender).attr('id') + '=>' + $(this).attr('id') + ' ' + (ui.item.index()+1) + ' ' + $(ui.item).text());
        }
    });

    $( ".heriyah" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Here is the sortable.php contents:

```
foreach ($_GET['sort'] as $position => $item) :
    $query = "UPDATE content SET `order` = $position WHERE `id` = $item";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
endforeach;
```

And here is how my page is set up:

```
<div id="someID" class="heriyah">
    <div id="heriyah_sortable" class="sort_1">Content</div>
    <div id="heriyah_sortable" class="sort_2">Content</div>
    <div id="heriyah_sortable" class="sort_3">Content</div>
    <div id="heriyah_sortable" class="sort_4">Content</div>
</div>
```

So nothing updates, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE (RESOLVED):**

Okay, so in my update query the path to my file was wrong, and besides that the update function itself was messed up.  So I fixed it to look like this now:

```
update : function (event, ui) {
        var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        $.post("admin/sortable.php?" + order);
},
```

Secondly, my query to the database was messed up.  The database wanted quotes around the PHP elements.  Sometimes the database doesn't care, but in certain instances it will error if there aren't quotes.  It's a good practice to put in slashed quotes ` around the column variables and then single quotes ' around the PHP variables in the query.

Here is what my query looks like now:

```
  $query = "UPDATE content SET `order` = '$position' WHERE `id` = '$item'";
```

Comment: if you're using chrome, open the developer tools by pressing F12 and click on the "network" tab and try sorting things. there should be a network activity on each sort operation, click one of them and in the details look what your post data is. If there isn't any post data, the sortable's serialize function may require something else or it's not working.

Comment: I'm using Firebug on my macbook, but it doesn't show anything, but I just updated the code above as well!

Comment: is there any network activity when you sort?

Comment: no activity at all.  There should be at least something!

Comment: put an alert inside the update event and check if it is popping.

Comment: alert is popping.  Can you tell if something is wrong with the AJAX or how the PHP is receiving it for sorting?

Comment: try .post, .get or .ajax instead of .load

Comment: Okay, well I think I figured out the issue, as soon as I resolve it I will post updated code as an answer.

Comment: Please, post your solution as an answer and mark it as the solution to help people with the same problem and close this question.

Comment: @rcdmk - it won't let me since I don't have 100 rep.  I have to wait 6 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so in my update query the path to my file was wrong, and besides that the update function itself was messed up.  So I fixed it to look like this now:

```
update : function (event, ui) {
        var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        $.post("admin/sortable.php?" + order);
},
```

Secondly, my query to the database was messed up.  The database wanted quotes around the PHP elements.  Sometimes the database doesn't care, but in certain instances it will error if there aren't quotes.  It's a good practice to put in slashed quotes ` around the column variables and then single quotes ' around the PHP variables in the query.

Here is what my query looks like now:

```
  $query = "UPDATE content SET `order` = '$position' WHERE `id` = '$item'";
```